# react native - dynamic reanimated2 entering and exiting animation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-reanimated-v2

I am using `reanimated2` for my react native project. I want to dynamically change the animation to `ZoomInLeft` or `ZoomInRight` based on the situation:

```
export default function SigninCard(props){
    const [zoomout,setZoomout] = useState('left')

    function handleExiting(s){
        console.log(s)
        setZoomout(s)
    }

    <Animated.View 
        style={{flex:1, alignItems:'center'}}
        entering={ZoomInRight}
        exiting={zoomout=='left' ? ZoomOutLeft : ZoomOutRight}
        ...
        <Button title='Register' onPress={()=>{
            handleExiting('left');
            parentgoto('userdetails';
        )}}
    />
        <Button title='Login' onPress={()=>{
                handleExiting('right');
                parentgoto('userdetails';
            )}}
        />
    </Animated.View>
}
```

Like to code above, I use `zoomout` variable to decide if I want the animation to go right or left, then set ternary condition in `exiting`. But somehow the animation will always go left. even I click on the right button.

After a few tests, I believe the decision factor is at the `useState('left')`. even though I `setZoomOut('right')`, it don't seems to change the state.

How can I resolve this? Or is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

the `<Animated.View />` seems to be the default one, so I assume that `exiting={zoomout=='left' ? ZoomOutLeft : ZoomOutRight}` is not being triggered since it's not a predefined property of the native `<View />` element.

What you could do is use an `useEffect()` hook in which you check the state and apply the animation. Below you can find an example:

```
export default function SigninCard(props){
  const [zoomout,setZoomout] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    switch(zoomout) {
      case 'left':
      ZoomOutLeft();
      break;

      case 'right':
      ZoomOutRight();
      break;

      default:
      break;
    }
  }, [zoomout]);

  return (<Animated.View 
      style={{flex:1, alignItems:'center'}}>
      <Button title='Register' onPress={()=>{
        setZoomout('left');
        parentgoto('userdetails');
      )}}
    
      <Button title='Login' onPress={()=>{
         setZoomout('right')
         parentgoto('userdetails');
      )}}
    />
  </Animated.View>);
}
```

I also assume that `entering={ZoomInRight}` won't work either, to fix it you can apply the same logic as shown above.

Comment: tried your method but got an error,`cannot call class as function.`. Any idea how to solve that?